# unbounded memory growth with no code involved

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I had a few memory issues with my app so I started investigate. Removed a few methods, profile -> instruments and again and again. I found a few major issues but my question is this, Right now I have a class with no code in it besides the basic `import` `viewdidload` etc (the build in lines you get when you create a new class. In the IB I've connected that class ViewController to another ViewController and I'm pushing my way back and forth. In instruments I can see that with every push I'm gaining 30-50kb to my app. How is that possible? Is that normal behavior?

Comment: What do you mean you're pushing back and forth? You should be pushing to the second view controller and then popping back to the first one. Including more details will help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segues create a new instance of the destination view controller each time. If you have two view controllers linked by segues in a storyboard, and you keep executing the segues, you will get more and more instances of each controller, so you would expect to see memory growth.

Look into unwind segues, or a navigation controller, or dismissing the presented view controller to go "back".